# Generate Authentication token and authenticate as a user manually in a controller

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using **Symfony2** and **FOSUserBundle**. I want to get a user with Doctrine ORM then logging in as it.

```
$user = $em->getRepository("InoUserBundle:User")->find(10);

// I want the security context as $user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like so:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, '12345', "admin", $user->getRolesAsArray());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

Comment: Thank you. What is `InteractiveLoginEvent` for ?

Comment: needed for the login event, this makes sure all event listeners for the login event are tirggerd